# Hourly Aggregation in PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to aggregate by hour my data. I want firstly to keep only hours in my evtTime. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Row(access=u'WRITE', 
    agentHost=u'xxxxxx50.haas.xxxxxx', 
    cliIP=u'192.000.00.000', 
    enforcer=u'ranger-acl', 
    event_count=1, 
    event_dur_ms=0, 
    evtTime=u'2017-10-01 23:03:51.337', 
    id=u'a43d824c-1e53-439b-b374-96b76bacf714', 
    logType=u'RangerAudit', 
    policy=699, 
    reason=u'/project-h/xxxx/xxxx/warehouse/rocq.db/f_crcm_res_temps_retrait', 
    repoType=1, 
    reqUser=u'rocqphadm', 
    resType=u'path', 
    resource=u'/project-h/xxxx/xxxx/warehouse/rocq.db/f_crcm_res_temps_retrait', 
    result=1, 
    seq_num=342976577)
```

My objectif subsequently is to group by reqUser and calculate the sum of event_count. I tried this :

```
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), DateType())
df1 = df.withColumn('DATE', func(col('evtTime')))

metrics_DataFrame = (df1
                 .groupBy(hour('DATE'), 'reqUser')
                 .agg({'event_count': 'sum'})
                )
```

This is the result :

```
[Row(hour(DATE)=0, reqUser=u'A383914', sum(event_count)=12114),
Row(hour(DATE)=0, reqUser=u'xxxxadm', sum(event_count)=211631),
Row(hour(DATE)=0, reqUser=u'splunk-system-user', sum(event_count)=48),
Row(hour(DATE)=0, reqUser=u'adm', sum(event_count)=7608),
Row(hour(DATE)=0, reqUser=u'X165473', sum(event_count)=2)]
```

My objectif is to get something like this :

```
[Row(hour(DATE)=2017-10-01 23:00:00, reqUser=u'A383914', sum(event_count)=12114),
Row(hour(DATE)=2017-10-01 22:00:00, reqUser=u'xxxxadm', sum(event_count)=211631),
Row(hour(DATE)=2017-10-01 08:00:00, reqUser=u'splunk-system-user', sum(event_count)=48),
Row(hour(DATE)=2017-10-01 03:00:00, reqUser=u'adm', sum(event_count)=7608),
Row(hour(DATE)=2017-10-01 11:00:00, reqUser=u'X165473', sum(event_count)=2)]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple possible solutions, the simplest one is to use only the required part as a string:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, to_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame(["2017-10-01 23:03:51.337"], "string").toDF("evtTime")

df.withColumn("hour", substring("evtTime", 0, 13)).show()
# +--------------------+-------------+                                            
# |             evtTime|         hour|
# +--------------------+-------------+
# |2017-10-01 23:03:...|2017-10-01 23|
# +--------------------+-------------+
```

or as a timestamp:

```
df.withColumn("hour", to_timestamp(substring("evtTime", 0, 13), "yyyy-MM-dd HH")).show()
# +--------------------+-------------------+
# |             evtTime|               hour|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
# |2017-10-01 23:03:...|2017-10-01 23:00:00|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
```

You could also `date_format`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, col

df.withColumn("hour", date_format(col("evtTime").cast("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:00")).show()
# +--------------------+----------------+
# |             evtTime|            hour|
# +--------------------+----------------+
# |2017-10-01 23:03:...|2017-10-01 23:00|
# +--------------------+----------------+
```

or `date_trunc`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc

df.withColumn("hour", date_trunc("hour", col("evtTime").cast("timestamp"))).show()
# +--------------------+-------------------+                                      
# |             evtTime|               hour|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
# |2017-10-01 23:03:...|2017-10-01 23:00:00|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
```