# PySpark date_trunc modifies the timezone: how to prevent it?

Tags: date, pyspark, timestamp, timezone, truncation

**Context:** I use [date_trunc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_trunc) function imported from pyspark.sql.functions to truncate timestamp to minutes.

```
df_truncated = df.withColumn('dt', date_trunc('minute', df["timestamp"]))
df_truncated.show(truncate=False)
```

The output is following

```
+------------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp               |dt                 |
+------------------------+-------------------+
|2020-01-02T00:30:47.178Z|2020-01-02 02:30:00|
|2020-01-02T00:30:47.160Z|2020-01-02 02:30:00|
|2020-01-02T00:30:46.327Z|2020-01-02 02:30:00|
|2020-01-02T00:30:45.003Z|2020-01-02 02:30:00|
|2020-01-02T00:30:44.054Z|2020-01-02 02:30:00|
+------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Problem:** The problem is that it "adds" two hours to the original timstamp - converts from utc to local time.

**Question:** How can I avoid this? Do I need to manually truncate the timestamp or there is some parameter for the date_trunc function that is not documented? Or do I need to access spark global settings and if so then how or which settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know.

```
##  Here i am selecting the substring of the column "timestamp". Choose everthing till the seconds and convert that to a timestamp.

df.withColumn("hour", F.to_timestamp(F.substring("timestamp_value", 0, 19), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).show()

+-------------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp                |hour               |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|2017-08-01T14:30:00+05:30|2017-08-01 14:30:00|
|2017-08-01T14:30:00+06:30|2017-08-01 14:30:00|
|2017-08-01T14:30:00+07:30|2017-08-01 14:30:00|
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

For some more techniques you can refer the link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946610/hourly-aggregation-in-pyspark)

Comment: So this falls under the "manual" approach. Had problem with the format parameter when I tried using to_timestamp function so thank you for that. Modified a little bit to truncate the timestamp down to minutes:
`df.withColumn("hour", F.date_trunc('minute',F.to_timestamp(F.substring("timestamp", 0, 19), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))).show()`